# Calculate percents inline in SQL query

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
SELECT User, COUNT(*) as count FROM Tests WHERE Release = '1.0' GROUP by User;
```

Above query will return distinct numbers, however, I would like to convert count to percents in relation to total number of records. Total number of records considering WHERE clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT R1.user, COUNT(*)/R2.COUNT_ALL AS Expr1
  FROM Releases R1,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) As COUNT_ALL FROM Releases WHERE Release = '1.0') R2
 WHERE R1.Release = '1.0'
 GROUP BY R1.user, R2.COUNT_ALL
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach that uses a single SELECT:

```
SELECT 
    Tests.User, 
    Count(IIf([Tests].[Release]='1.0', 1, Null)) / Count(*) AS Percentage
FROM 
    Tests
GROUP BY 
    Tests.User
```

Unlike the approaches suggested earlier, this one will, for better or worse, return records for users having no records in Tests where Release is "1.0".  If you don't want these records, you could add a HAVING clause to eliminate them.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

Like Brian's answer but in standard SQL instead of MS Access only. (One can also use `COUNT` instead of `SUM` with `NULL` where I have `0`.)

```
SELECT 
    Tests.User, 
    Sum(CASE WHEN Release='1.0' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / Count(*) AS Percentage
FROM 
    Tests
GROUP BY 
    Tests.User
```

Comment: How is it useful to have an answer that doesn't work for the database engine in the actual question? It would be one thing to include an Access/Jet/ACE solution and then offer the non-Access method, too, but I don't see that this answer adds anything at all here that is of any use -- it will just confuse people looking for a solution that applies to Access/Jet/ACE.

Comment: An answer that's been deleted badmouths Access for allegedly not supporting PARTITION BY, but the fact is, Access/Jet/ACE SQL does have a Partition() function that might work here (I'm not certain if it does or not). It's definitely worth reading the help file for it, as when I first encountered it a couple of years ago, I was surprised it existed.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: Because someone is likely to hit this page in a search, that's why, and an Access-only solution won't do them any good. AFAIK, the standard SQL `CASE` statement works in Access too, and is therefore much preferable.

Comment: @Andrew: `CASE` does **not** work in Access. That's why the answer is potentially harmful (confusing).

Comment: @Andrew Lazarus: "As far as I know" -- that's the key point here. You obviously DON'T know what applies to Access and what doesn't, and you're being told here that you've posted something that is inapplicable.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: And when someone who doesn't use Access finds this page in a search? Well, whatever makes your day, bro.

Comment: The question is about getting the desired result in Access, not in any generic database. Answers to Access questions with T-SQL in them are useless. Don't you actually test your answers in the appropriate environment before posting them? I always do (unless I'm posting existing code that's already in use and known to work)!